# Can I use variadic templates in a lambda?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, lambda, variadic-templates

Can I make this work?

Imaginary syntax:

```
auto foo = [] () { };
template <class T, typename ... Args>
auto foo =
[&] (T && V, Args && ... args) {
    do_something(V);
    foo(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
};
```

Comment: I think C++14 lets you do this: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/386d6f281077b336

Comment: How would you use that? It looks kind of like a variable template (which isn't allowed at block scope in C++1y). As a polymorphic lambda, see chris' solution. In C++11, you can implement that as a full-blown function object class.

Comment: There's some trouble with the pseudo-recursive invocation of `foo`: the identifier may not appear in the initializer for a declaration with `auto`. (Also, you can't overload lambdas, but I guess that's part of the question.)

Comment: @chris You can combine this (the polymorphic variadic lambda) with a (local) function object type to get overloading and this pseudo-recursion. Which I think then is an answer.

Comment: @dyp, I haven't played around with variadic lambdas enough to do anything useful. I'd love to see your idea fleshed out as an answer.

Comment: @chris Maybe something [like this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e2b58946c441cd95)?

Comment: @dyp, Okay, I see what you're getting at. Not too shabby considering it's implement once and use indefinitely. Seems like a worthy answer with credit to you, assuming C++14 is acceptable. If it isn't, the question doesn't really have an answer that uses lambdas like this anyway, unless Boost has magically evolved to do that since I last saw. Come to think of it, a polymorphic Boost.Phoenix would be cool.

Comment: @dyp: They are part of question now. I didn't knew at time I created the question that I can't overload lambdas or do a recursive call.

Comment: I always come up against this sort of thing, but always had to find other ways ... would love to have templated lambdas ...

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments you can't really do this as lambdas aren't powerful enough.

When the `[](auto val){}` syntax is allowed this will be much easier.

I use the following for basic calling over tuples.:

```
template<typename Tuple_t, typename Func_t, std::size_t k_index = 0>
//Only come here if the passed in index is less than sie of tuple
    typename std::enable_if<k_index <  tuple_size<Tuple_t>::value>::type 
    call_over_tuple(Tuple_t& irk_tuple, Func_t i_func){

    i_func(get<k_index>(irk_tuple));
    call_over_tuple<Tuple_t, Func_t, k_index + 1>(irk_tuple, i_func);

}

template<typename Tuple_t, typename Func_t, std::size_t k_index>
typename std::enable_if < k_index >=  tuple_size<Tuple_t>::value>::type
    call_over_tuple(Tuple_t& irk_tuple, Func_t i_func){
             //do nothing
}
```

Expanding this to just random args gives.

```
template<typename Func_t, typename ...Args>
void call_over_vals(Func_t i_func, Args&&... i_args){

    auto arg_tuple = make_tuple(forward<Args>(i_args)...);

    call_over_tuple<decltype(arg_tuple), Func_t>(arg_tuple, i_func);
}
```

In order to have function overloading or templates you need to create a caller class that does your bidding.

```
template<typename T>
void do_something(const T& irk_val){
    cout << irk_val;
}

class caller_class{
public:

    template<typename T>
    void operator()(const T& i_val){
        do_something(i_val);
    }
private:

};

void print_integer(int i_val){
    cout << i_val;
}

int main(int argv, char** argc){

    call_over_vals(caller_class(), 3, ' ' ,  2, " asdf ", 4, "\n");


    //If you know the argument type just pass it in
    call_over_vals(print_integer, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

    cout << "\n";

    call_over_vals([](int y_val){cout << y_val; }, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
}
```

Output:

```
3 2 asdf 4
12345
12345
```